# "Merge Selected Features" Persistently Grayed Out

Tags: qgis, polygon, mergeshapes

I am perplexed by a new occurrence in QGIS,  I seem unable to merge selected features e.g. Polygon.   Toggling Editing on a polygon layer,  and selecting two polygon features I would like to merge into one,  the merge polygon feature is always greyed out using the digitizing tools toolbar.  Now I have tried the following:

1. Saving the polygon in a different CRS (Save as)
2. Creating a simple polygon feature to compare the results (same results cannot merge any polygon features as the function is greyed out)
3. Restarting in a new project.
4. Updating QGIS to the latest version 2.18.7
5. Testing it on multiple polygon datasets.
6. Checking geometry.

Still the merge selected features is always greyed out no matter what I do.

Am I doing something wrong?   I have used this feature in the past but now it is not working at all. I am not a GIS expert; just using it for creating simple maps.

[image]

Comment: I guess you mean the toolbar of the plugin "Digitizing Tools". I think you should use the toolbar "Digitizing Toolbar".

Answer (score 5):

The issue of the greyed out merge feature function is in the Digitizing Tools toolbar. When the Advanced Editing toolbar is used, the merge feature function (button) is available. These toolbars have many of the same functions and look very similar at first glance.

If this are polygon from the same layer you should do this steps:

1)Select the polygons with the "Select Features"[image]
2)Press the "Merge Selected Features" button [image]
3)A box will open: Press "OK"[image]

If the original polygons are interconnected you will have a new integrated polygon.[image].

Comment: The thing is I am using the select features function,  but when I select the two polygons as seen in the image I attached the "Merge  Selected Features"  Tool still remains greyed out,  it is baffling me like I said I have used this function many times.   I follow the steps exactly as mentioned and still it is greyed out.  Thank you for the answer though, much appreciated.

Comment: @J.Pereira Please see the comment by Mike, too. By activating `View | Toolbars | Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` you will find almost identical "Merge Selected Features" button there. Then Nitzan's answer should work.

Comment: @Mike (apologies for not realizing what you meant) yes that worked perfectly thank you very much.  My Advanced Digitizing Toolbar was disabled.   That was rather confusing! Now I can merge.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help

Comment: Can you please mark question this as "answered"

Comment: This does not work for me in QGIS3 trying to merge lines :-(

Comment: Just to note that you may still need to "Toggle Editing" (the yellow pencil icon, 8th from the left on the Data Source Manager Toolbar)